# Eclipse on mac: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 error

Tags: java

So before anyone tells  me there are other answer to this, I have looked at them and have done all I could. I have updated the JRE AND JDK, and I still receive this error when trying to run my project I have compiled on my PC. Here is what I receive when I type in `java -version`

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Also when I go to eclipse to edit the build path, and select a new library, I have NO JRE's compatibly with Java 7.0 but I explicitly downloaded the JRE 7 not 30 minutes ago!

I am lost and I need some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: nope I have the correct two downloaded

Comment: JDK - "jdk-7u25-macosx-x64.dmg"
JRE - "jre-7u25-macosx-x64.dmg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want to check Installed JREs:
`Preferences > Java > Installed JREs` If the JDK7 is not in the list, you should add it by clicking `Add...` button.

1. Click `Add...` button
2. Select `Standard VM` in the list and click `Next` button
3. Specify the `JRE home:` by clicking `Directory...` button
4. Specify the `JRE name:` properly and click `Finish` button
5. In Preferences dialog, make JRE7 as default