# Omnet++ 5.2 mac installation : Error

Tags: java, macos, macos-sierra, omnet++

I follow all steps of the installation guide and when I try to open the omnet get this error: 
An error ha ocurred. See the log file Users/xxxX/omnetpp-5.2/ide/omnetpp.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/1509461950402.log

The log file contains that:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2017-10-31 16:19:02.116
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/adaptor/EclipseStarter : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
```

Comment: There are various answers to this Eclipse / macOS question here on Stackoverflow already!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397370/eclipse-on-mac-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error
or 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858915/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-on-mac

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem(s;) and I think it's due to `java.version=9.0.1` which does not work well with Eclipse coming with OMNeT++. My solution was as follows:

- Install java8 using brew as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342886/how-to-install-java-8-on-mac). I.e.,

`brew tap caskroom/versions`

`brew cask install java8`

- Update `$PATH` pointing to java8

`export PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/:$PATH`

After that I didn't get the error documented in ..omnetpp-5.2/samples/.metadata/.log and OMNeT++ IDE did start. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Now Omnet starts opening, the window to choose the workspace appears and it get me this error:See the log file
/Users/unaicenigaonandia/omnetpp-5.2/samples/.metadata/.log.

The log file content:

```
 !SESSION 2017-11-02 11:08:27.511 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=5.2.0.170929-f95315d
java.version=9.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=es_ES
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-02 11:08:51.503
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 24 more
```